# Sound static in VLC Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: sound, alsa, vlc

When I set the audio output module to Pulseaudio, Audio memory, or Open Sound System, the sound works sometimes, but usually is very staticy.

If I switch to Alsa, the sound works fine, but if I pause the video, when I unpause it, there is no sound. I have to quit VLC and open it back up.

Any ideas how I could fix one of the other audio modules? My google search seems to suggest this is a bug with older VLC versions. I have VLC 2.0.3 (the packaged version that comes with this Ubuntu version).

Answer (score 1):

I've had the problem in 12.04. I now have 12.10 and vlc 2.0.4 and it seems even worse. Installing `phonon-backend-vlc` only shorten the static noise to 10 seconds at the start of play. So it was only partially useful.

I then went into `Tools > Preferences > Audio` and set `Output module:` to `ALSA audio output`. I remember reading about this solution before, but it does not always work. It seems to work now with `phonon-backend-vlc` installed. I closed VLC, opened VLC again, and played a video file. The static is completely gone.

Good luck. I have no idea why this works. You can always set it back to `Output Module: Default` if it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the link below: install `phonon-backend-vlc` (works in ubuntu 12.04 x86)

- http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1978333

Easy!

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: This did not fix the problem for me :(